# $\lim a_{n} = a \Rightarrow \lim a_{n}^{p} = a_{}^{p}$ for $0 \leq p < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $(a_{n})$ is a sequence, $\lim a_{n} = a$, and $a_{n} \geq 0$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Does this imply $\lim a_{n}^{p} = a_{}^{p}$ for all $0 \leq p < \infty$?

The answer is clear for $p \in \mathbb{N}$, and it has been shown numerous times on this website for $p = \frac{1}{2}$. But does it hold for all $0 \leq p < \infty$?

Comment: you could take logarithm and you'll see that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Let $f: x \mapsto x^p$. Then $f$ is continuous at $a$, which means that $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0$ for which $|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$.

If $a_n \to a$ then we have that $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists N$ so that $n > N \implies |a_n-a|<\varepsilon$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given, and let $\delta$ be appropriate for our $f$ and $\varepsilon$.  Then by the convergence of $(a_n)$, we see that $\exists N$ for which $n>N \implies |a_n-a| < \delta$. This means that, $\forall n > N$ we have that
$$|a_n^p-a^p|=|f(a_n)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$$

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thank you very much!